# Computing e^x for any x with Taylor series

Tags: c

I know its pretty bad beginner code but I think it should work, why doesn't it?

It's probably my condidtion `haufen != haufen_alt` that causes some problems but maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double fak(k){
    double i, f_haufen = 1;

    for (i=1; i <= k; i++){
        f_haufen = f_haufen*i;
    }
    return f_haufen;
}

double e_hoch (double x){
    double haufen, haufen_alt, k;

    haufen = 0;
    haufen_alt = 0;
    k = 0;
    do{
        haufen_alt = haufen;
        haufen += (pow(x,k))/(fak(k));
        k++;
    }while(haufen != haufen_alt);

    return haufen;
}

int main (void){
    double x_main;
    printf("x=");
    scanf("%lf", &x_main);

    printf("e^%.2f = %f",x_main, e_hoch(x_main));
}
```

Comment: @John Kugelman As far as I understand `(pow(x,k))/(fak(k))` should become smaller and smaller and end up as being evaluated as 0 at some point. That's why I picked the condition.

Comment: @drachenwort: please learn to use your debugger.  Step through the code, look at the variables as your program executes.  Specifically, look at the values of f_haufen in fak(), and haufen and haufen_alt in e_hoch().  Learning to use your debugger is an ESSENTIAL skill.  I think you'll find some instructive "surprises" as you step through the code.  Q: What C compiler, debugger and/or IDE are you using?

Comment: If I pass in 1 as the input the result is `e^1.00 = 1.000000` which is incorrect right? The logic is flawed.

Comment: Writing a good function for calculating _e^x_ is a non-trivial exercise.

Comment: @John Kugelman: Sadly I can't really answer your question, since I'm pretty much completely new to programming and am just using, what was given to me.

Comment: @stanle: yeah that is also concerning me, but the formula to calculate it should be correct, and I seem to be incapable of finding the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`haufen` and `haufen_alt` will always be different by a nonzero factor of `(pow(x,k))/(fak(k))`. The factor will get smaller and smaller approaching zero, but it won't actually reach zero since the numerator is nonzero.

The standard procedure is to decide on some epsilon threshold *close* to zero you want to stop at. When the next addend drops below epsilon, or when the difference between successive terms is less than epsilon, stop. That lets you tune how accurate you want the result to be. The smaller epsilon the more accurate it'll be but the longer it'll take.

Comment: I tried `while (abs(haufen - haufen_alt) > 0.00001)` as a condition and it still doesn't give any good results

Comment: Make that `fabs`. `abs` is for integers.

Comment: Or drop the `abs` altogether, since the difference will always be positive.

Comment: @John Kugelman: Ah thank you, it works now. I didn't knew `abs` was limited to integers and put it there for safety.